# adding String Array in Popover ViewController in swift

Tags: swift

I'm starting iOS development and I Would like to know how to insert  a

```
var typeBugList = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

into a ViewController through a popover. At the moment i have this code below, which can show the ViewController through the popover :

```
@IBAction func PopoverType(sender: UIButton)
 {


    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(
        name: "BugReporting",
        bundle: nil)
    let menuTypeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuTypeViewController")

    menuTypeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    menuTypeViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200)

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuTypeViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Left
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = (sender as UIView)
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

    presentViewController(menuTypeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

In your MenuTypeViewController file add

```
var myArray : [String]
```

And your function should be something like

```
@IBAction func PopoverType(sender: UIButton)
 {


    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(
        name: "BugReporting",
        bundle: nil)
    let menuTypeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuTypeViewController")

    menuTypeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    menuTypeViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200)

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuTypeViewController.popoverPresentationController

    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Left
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = (sender as UIView)
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds

    menuTypeViewController.myArray = typeBugList

    presentViewController(menuTypeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You need to cast the result of `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to the correct type, because `UIViewController` has no `myArray` property.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i was answering, but then in which type should i cast it?

Comment: At the moment i haven't any MenuTypeViewController file because i had thought that it was just a popover. Can i write a popover containing a table view in the same ViewController file as the parent view?

Comment: Yes you can. Just assign the delegate and datasource of the PopOver view controller's tableview to self, and in self implement the methods for numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections and cellForRowAtIndexPath to return the content from your array

Comment: Ok, to make the code more clearer i did 2 swift files and i added a marray property into the MenuTypeViewController. Why can't i access to the myArray property through  the other swift file?